# Intellij Idea 14 - disable highlighting level messages

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, inspections

I recently moved from Eclipse to Intellij idea and i'm trying to customize it. I was wondering whether is posible to disable the description popup messages on the highlighting level, I don't want to disable the inspections, only the message because when the cursor is over the scrollbar, the popup blocks the scrollbar. I've already searched in settings, editor, inspection, but i haven't find how to disable it:

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible. And, it shouldn't matter that the message is above the scrollbar -- it shouldn't block it.

Comment: yes, it shouldn't, but it does. When I try to drag the scrollbar, if a  message pop ups, it consumes the click and I end dragging nothing.

Comment: I've just tried to replicate your results, but in Idea 13 this message /always/ pops up to the left of the scroll bar.

Comment: I'm seeing popups to the left of the scrollbar in WebStorm, but in Android Studio there are popups that cover it (and consume the click).  Maybe there's a plugin that is responsible, but I haven't tracked it down yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click scrollbar > Customize Highlighting Level > Switch to "None"

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to disable those popups. They are intended to be transparent for all mouse operations on the scrollbar, and I wasn't able to reproduce the problem that you describe (that they interfere with dragging the scrollbar).